# Populating Excel file with a 3D list - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a 3D list where the entry of each sub-list is not always a list:

```
example_list = [
    [123, 'name surname 1', 'job title 1', ['Entry 1', 'Exit 1'], [123, 123], 'Reason for flag'],
    [456, 'name surname 2', 'job title 2', ['Entry 2', 'Exit 2'], [456, 456], 'Reason for flag']
]
```

I am trying to put this into an excel spreadsheet using the following method:

```
import pandas as pd

example_list = [
    [123, 'name surname 1', 'job title 1', ['Entry 1', 'Exit 1'], [123, 123], 'Reason for flag'],
    [456, 'name surname 2', 'job title 2', ['Entry 2', 'Exit 2'], [456, 456], 'Reason for flag']
]

filename = 'test'

def write_to_spreadsheet(iterable, document_name):

    df = pd.DataFrame(iterable)
    df.to_excel(excel_writer = f'{document_name}.xlsx')

write_to_spreadsheet(iterable=example_list, document_name=filename)
```

This gives me a spreadsheet that looks like the following:

[image]

However, I would like to have an output that looks like:

[image]

Essentially expanding the inner lists (which can vary in length, so they won't necessarily take up a set number of rows).

I have seen a few answers, but each has dealt with multidimensional lists where each entry is of the `list` type.

**Additional Info:**

The reason I have not used a dictionary is because it is easier to use lists in the rest of my project, and keys (such as the 'name surname') are potentially repeated. For this reason, I have not tried the `pandas.DataFrame.explode()` method (as, from my understanding, keys are used as column headings).

Comment: try: `df.set_index([0,1,2,5]).apply(pd.Series.explode)`

Comment: may be you can replace them with a empty string.

Comment: @Pygirl Your first suggestion seems to have no effect - I may be implementing it incorrectly: I placed it right after defining the dataframe, is this correct?
As for the empty strings, I would like to avoid that, because the sublists can be very long, and the matrix is fairly large overall.

Comment: Check my answer can you save that dataframe `x`  in your excel  format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
x = df.set_index([0,1,2,5]).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
g = lambda col: x[col].duplicated()
x.loc[g(0) & g(1) & g(2) & g(5), [0,1,2,5]] = ''
```

---

**x:**

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 | name surname 1 | job title 1 | Reason for flag | Entry 1 | 123 |
| 1 |  |  |  |  | Exit 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 | name surname 2 | job title 2 | Reason for flag | Entry 2 | 456 |
| 3 |  |  |  |  | Exit 2 | 456 |

For general solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
mask = df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list))
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
df.loc[df.index.duplicated(), ~mask] = ''
```

Comment: This works well, thank you very much. Do you mind giving me a brief explanation on what your lambda function does? I'm getting a bit lost there.

Comment: added to answer general solution ;)

Comment: @ChaddRobertson: It's just an anonymous function. You can define function like this also: `def func(col): return x[col].duplicated()`

Comment: You two are phenomenal, thanks for the assist. The general solution is a great include.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson: that `set_index` and `reset_index` are un necessary use `x=df.apply(pd.Series.explode)` I was doing something else before with index thing so forgot to edit that line.